# Running a pbk file in Linux

Tags: fedora, networking

To connect to my university's network, they provided me with a .pbk file.
The file is made for windows of course and I have no idea how to use it in Fedora
(I'm using Fedora 15)

Comment: What does `file /path/to/file.pbk` show?

Answer (score 1):

The .pbk file is a plaintext INI-style file used by Windows XP RAS, which means you should be able to open it up in a text editor and extract useful information. If it's just a simple dial-up connection, all you should need is the `PhoneNumber` field.